# Request flow of Magento 2

Tags: magento2, architecture, mvc

Their is a lot of fuss going about `Magento 2`, concept like Namespaces etc has been incorporated into it. I am just curious to know how REQUEST flow has been handled in `Magento 2`, can somebody give me a brief .

Interesting point from Anthol Krit Presentation

> Magneto2 has got **8000** classes compare to **2700** in Magento 1

Comment: Magento 2 architect Anton Kril explains it here: http://de.slideshare.net/Dutchento/anton-kril-mm15nl

Comment: @FabianSchmengler its not working now

Answer (score 22):

`index.php` creates application instance (`\Magento\Framework\App\Http`) using objectManager (that is created before that in bootstrap) and calls method `launch`.

Http Application instance does initial routing: it takes first part of url to figure out which area should be loaded (admin/frontend/rest/...).

When area is defined, configuration for that area is loaded (unlike Magento 1 where all configuration was loaded).

Then application object calls `Magento\Framework\App\FrontControllerInterface::dispatch` of requested area. Front Controller does routing same as in Magento 1: all routers are iterated to match request. The router that matches the request returns instance of ActionController matched to `FrontController`. This process is more efficient 
because only routers of one area are used (admin router is not used in frontend). All the extra behavior was moved from front controller to `plugins` of `FrontController` and Action Controllers.

When `FrontController` gets instance of action controller it calls `dispatch` on it. Action controller performs its task and returns instance of some implementation of `ResultInterface` (like page, redirect, ...).

`FrontController` just returns `ResultInterface` to Application Instance that renders the response.

I did presentation on this at Meet Magento NL:
[http://www.slideshare.net/Dutchento/anton-kril-mm15nl](http://www.slideshare.net/Dutchento/anton-kril-mm15nl?ref=https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72923/request-flow-of-magento-2)

Comment: Thnaks @anthon for your answer .

Comment: Ill be taking much time to grasp the full concept it seems

Answer (score 5):

Check the below links. The request flow is defined very nicely.

http://www.dckap.com/blog/request-flow-in-magento-2/

http://brideo.co.uk/magento2/Request-Flow-In-Magento-2/

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few resources on the topic for anybody who is interested:

- http://brideo.co.uk/magento2/Request-Flow-In-Magento-2/
- http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-request-routing/
- http://inchoo.net/magento-2/routing-in-magento-2/