# How Magento 2 Routing Works

Tags: controllers, magento2, routing, http-request

I need to know how magento 2 Routing Works...
I want to know that when we request for any task in magento 2 then how its process to controller...
Like I used command line console...'
Then how my request is routing to controller.....
Is it based on Zend Framework 2 concept or any else...
in this code 
I want to know about the routing process of Magento2..like how its routing works...when we request for any task..from front end...
please give answer

Comment: Magento 2 still use Zend Framework 1

Comment: http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/66795503174/notes-on-magento-2-routing

Comment: The home page (empty route path) is handled as a special case, detailed here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143287/how-does-home-page-routing-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is very good presentation ["Magento 2 Request Flow"](http://www.slideshare.net/Dutchento/anton-kril-mm15nl) by Anton Kril form Meet Magento NL 2015

[image]

Here is also info about rounting in [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/routing.html)

Comment: Here is also Anton explain himself http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72923/request-flow-of-magento-2