# How is Magento 2 RouterList Populated?

Tags: magento2, routing, router

How does Magento2 populate its `$routerList` in :

```
public function dispatch(RequestInterface $request)
{
    \Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('routers_match');
    $routingCycleCounter = 0;
    $result = null;
    while (!$request->isDispatched() && $routingCycleCounter++ < 100) {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface $router */
        foreach ($this->_routerList as $router) {
            try {
                $actionInstance = $router->match($request);
                if ($actionInstance) {
                    $request->setDispatched(true);
                    $this->response->setNoCacheHeaders();
                    $result = $actionInstance->dispatch($request);
                    break;
                }
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException $e) {
                $request->initForward();
                $request->setActionName('noroute');
                $request->setDispatched(false);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('routers_match');
    if ($routingCycleCounter > 100) {
        throw new \LogicException('Front controller reached 100 router match iterations');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Here is useful info about Magento 2 routing system in general http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/82123/2282

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 2 RouterList populated by DI configuration. See: [di.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/UrlRewrite/etc/frontend/di.xml#L9)

Please read [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/routing.html) for more details