# how magento 2 code called

Tags: magento2

I've started with magento2 two months ago, and I was developing APIs, So I've some issue with how magento code is called.

for example if I press on category to display its products, what are sequence of functions called so that products displayed.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72923/request-flow-of-magento-2

Comment: Yes, that's what I need to understand. Thanks a lot